# Is DeLong test valid for comparing two independent AUCs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, auc

I would like to know if DeLong test valid for comparing two independent AUCs? or it is only for two dependent AUCs?

Comment: @Frank Harrell your input is appreciated.